# how do i merge n .csv files(possibly 20-30 files) with 1 BIG .csv file horizontally(axis=1) using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a 20-30 csv files containing 3 columns like 'id','col1','col2','col3' and 1 big csv file of 20GB size that i want to read in chunks and merge with these samller csv files.
the bigger csv file has columns as 'id','name','zipdeails'.
both have ID column in same sequences, 
smaple looks like

```
 'id','name','zipdeails'
  1,Ravi,2031345
  2,Shayam,201344
  3,Priya,20134
  .........
  1000,Pravn,204324
```

chunk file 1 looks like

```
 'id','col1','col2','col3'
    1,Heat,,
    2,Goa,Next,
    3,,,Delhi
```

all the smaller csv files are of same lenth(number of rows) except for the last file which may be smaller in length with header in each. the bigger csv file to which these are to be merged can be broken into chunksize that is equal to the length of these smaller files
so Last chunk looks like

```
'id','col1','col2','col3'
   1000,Jaipur,Week,Trip
```

Now the output should look like

```
'id','name','zipdeails','col1','col2','col3'
 1,Ravi,2031345,Heat,NAN,NAN
 2,Shayam,201344,Goa,Next,NAN
 3,Priya,20134,NAN,NAN,Delhi
  .........
 1000,Pravn,204324,Jaipur,Week,Trip
```

Comment: Output is `30` merged DataFrames or one big dataframes by concating 30 + 1 big dataframe?

Comment: Also there is same `id` ordering in `big df` and each `small df` like `id in big df - > 1, 2, 3..., 1000`, in `small df -> 1,2,...,100` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need create `list of DataFrame`s for all small files, then read big file to memory and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all together by `index` created by `id` column:

```
import glob

#concat 30 files
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['id']) for fp in files]

#if necessary
#df_big = df_big.set_index('id')
df_fin = pd.concat([df_big, dfs], axis=1)
```

There is possible solution a bit modify if there is same order of `id` values in all DataFrames without duplicates like `1,2,3...N` with parameter `nrows` for read only first rows of big `DataFrame` by max length of smaller DataFrames:

```
#concat 30 files
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['a']) for fp in files]

len_max= max([x.index.max() for x in dfs])

df_big= pd.read_csv('big_df_file.csv', index_col=['id'], nrows=len_max)

df_fin = pd.concat([df_big, dfs], axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
#concat 30 files
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
#order of files is important for concat values - 
#in first file are id = (1,100), second (101, 200)...
print (files)

#set by max rows of file
N = 100
#loop by big fileby chunk define in N
for i, x in enumerate(pd.read_csv('files/big.csv', chunksize=N, index_col=['id'])):
    #added try for avoid errors if want seelct non exist file in list files
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(files[i], index_col=['id'])
        df1 = pd.concat([x, df], axis=1)
        print (df1)
        #in first loop create header in output
        if i == 0:
            pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns).to_csv('files/out.csv')
        #append data to output file
        df1.to_csv('files/out.csv', mode='a', header=False)

    except IndexError as e:
        print ('no files in list')
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that I've memory constraint.
Upon merging all the samller csv files the total size comes around to 10-20GB and then the bigger csv fiels is also of approx 10-20GB....loading such huge files into memory wouldn't solve my purpose. This is also why i wanted to accomplish this with the concepts of processing in chunks.

Comment: Also there is same id ordering in big df and each small df like id in `big df - > 1, 2, 3..., 1000`, in small `df -> 1,2,...,100` ?

Comment: yea the ids are unique and ordered.
for instance, id in bigger csv files 1,2,3,4.....100
and smaller ones will have ids like 1,2,3,4....10 and while the other smaller csv won't have the already used ids, its ids will start from 11,12,13,14,....20 and so on

Comment: yes. This is why i wanted to go with the concepts of merging in chunks.
the smaller csv are small in size when compared individually so they can be loaded into the memory individually but loading them all as a whole would be very costly in terms of memory

Comment: Hmmm, I am thinking about solution. Do you think it should be better memory optimal if chnksize is by length of smaller files, then in loop concat and then append to list of dataframes? Or write to 30 files? What do you need?

Comment: i just want the final output file to have data of all the columns of bigger csv and columns of smaller csv without much load to the memory. I believe this can be done by merging based on column 'id' in chunks of length(no. of rows) of smaller csv files then writing to another csv file(the output csv)

but as I'm a newbie to python, i'm not being able to do it hence the question on stackoverflow.

Comment: hey @jezrael thanks for the answer but i'm getting an error as

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 1385, saw 2`

Comment: It seems some data related error, is possible omit this lines? [Check here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#handling-bad-lines)

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael :)